# How to update Rails version on shared hosting server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have shared hosting server on bigrock.com and there is Ruby installed version 1.9 but it supports Rails 3 version and I am learning Rails 4.0.1. I talked with server support but got no answer.

So question is is there any way I can deploy Rails 4 application on my server or I will switch some other server.

As I told I am learner and can't afford money. Big rock is cheapest server I have seen. Yes I know there is Heroku but there are too many limitations for free user and for premiere user it is costly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Rails 4 if your ruby version is 1.9.3+

Rails [Documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html) says

**Ruby 2.0 preferred; 1.9.3+ required**

Include rails version in your Gemfile.

For example

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.1'
```

Comment: Well that is my question how i can as i am using shared hosting and there is rails 3 pre installed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your hosting supports rails 4 since thats the latest. Did you add rails version in your Gemfile?

Comment: No i didn't but it could be possible as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Rails 4 prefers Ruby 2.0

The best way is install your own ruby 2 by Ruby Version Manager (RVM) if you can

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
rvm install 2
```

An other way is buy a cheap VPS like 15$/year or $5/month

Comment: he asked about Rails, not about Ruby. Also, this probably isn't possible on shared hosting.

Comment: @sevenseacat rails 4 require ruby 2. that why I say so.

Comment: no it doesn't. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.0.0/rails.gemspec 1.9.3+.

Comment: @sevenseacat sorry, rails 4 prefer ruby 2